Decrypt RC4 with Python knowing the key
I come here with a little problem (sorry for my english this is not my mothertongue).
I have a little malware project at school, globally I have a keylogger which create a file and then encrypt the content of this file with RC4 ecnryption. (below two examples of different content of this file)
First one
========================
î³É†"Û4ZôßaV0%í;ËüüòaÐAiúˆcdÖ&

Second one
========================

ä¡Çš3µ{²agÄ}W8%í–YœèáŒ9¯ŽW‰‚”&ÂIAžŠmá'8V¡Uñši&Ædà·…í^ê¥>´©ÍjÌ{

ŒFÔ¿%ïÆñyFÎ3x°º“A)o4´´­‡—ÆéâùyÕ p‑@­®á÷Lì-»›ys‘ñî“wõl„/•+
w×jc´E"Ø¾‑øSG,Üo`ürx;¼¡T#üdÊ-‡k«G‘å”b¿+†]Ù©–f:^É( ÁË è­Pàv8¹|ç±ŸD7…ÁSgœÛÚjá"æ‡=I•Âa|âOÄÝ\Ùþ×Æçð©Ð¨Û•Øâ¿tù5¾à…y¸Æy

========================

‰Î$œk{²aÎž:Xyc¢“ðÆ¯¨ÉxéÁR ËÌ~Ž

========================

IéÓí­q3C¦_Å)$Ãü¥Âƒ7Ð&èIÎž:XycjõúØ·v¯ìzëà—'ì`

========================

±Öšk{ð,•Ã{V4#

========================

ü§ÎâK³[’2…×bx2|p‚³ÐæˆéXÉár ëì^ iÈòãˆK7Ï4àZG¯

‰—¥ÃpÂTÅÎ¹ Âu‚HÚ±+ïÈñýjÂ«=v¾´O'a°Äß­‰—ÆéìùyÕ ž@­®á÷Bì#»›w}‘þã“wûl„/›% yÙdmºK"Ø¾‑ùPI"Üo`ürx;¼¡T#ü

========================

 

========================

õ¡‹Ñ$Ý:þ;‡›iT|É9ZlcÒCkøŠafÔ$ãB™izl*Wò¾ójÐÃÄ

========================

 

========================

Now by doing some reverse engineering stuff I have found the key which is If you want to keep a secret, you must also hide it from yourself
So my goal was to decrypt the content of the file in order to see what kind of data the keylogger is writing so here is my python code (based on the wikipedia page of RC4).
#!/usr/bin/env python
class WikipediaARC4:
    def __init__(self, key = None):
        self.state = list(range(256)) # initialisation de la table de permutation
        self.x = self.y = 0 # les index x et y, au lieu de i et j
  
        if key is not None:
            self.init(key)
  
    # Key schedule
    def init(self, key):
        for i in range(256):
            self.x = (ord(key[i % len(key)]) + self.state[i] + self.x) & 0xFF
            self.state[i], self.state[self.x] = self.state[self.x], self.state[i]
        self.x = 0
  
    # Générateur
    def crypt(self, input):
        output = [None]*len(input)
        for i in range(len(input)):
            self.x = (self.x + 1) & 0xFF
            self.y = (self.state[self.x] + self.y) & 0xFF
            self.state[self.x], self.state[self.y] = self.state[self.y], self.state[self.x]
            output[i] = chr((ord(input[i]) ^ self.state[(self.state[self.x] + self.state[self.y]) & 0xFF]))
        return ''.join(output)
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_vectors = [['If you want to keep a secret, you must also hide it from yourself', 'î³É†"Û4ZôßaV0%í;ËüüòaÐAiúˆcdÖ&']]
    for i in test_vectors:
        print(i[0])
        print(WikipediaARC4(i[0]).crypt(i[1]))

When I launch my code this is my output
If you want to keep a secret, you must also hide it from yourself xBë⁃ìÖú½ÜûuåÐÅÙrJM©[&$5ȿÅk
So here is my question, I don't really know if this is really it because the decrypted content doesn't seem to have a particular meaning, Has any of you some thoughts about it ?
Thanks guys !
Edit: the two functions of the RC4 in the malware
void __cdecl initRC4(int param_1,int param_2)

{
  undefined uVar1;
  uint local_10;
  int local_c;
  int local_8;

                    /* 0x1530  2  initRC4 */
  local_8 = 0;
  for (local_c = 0; local_c < 0x100; local_c = local_c + 1) {
    *(char *)(param_1 + local_c) = (char)local_c;
  }
  for (local_10 = 0; (int)local_10 < 0x100; local_10 = local_10 + 1) {
    local_8 = (int)((uint)*(byte *)(param_1 + local_10) + local_8 +
                   (uint)*(byte *)(param_2 + (local_10 & 3))) % 0x100;
    uVar1 = *(undefined *)(param_1 + local_10);
    *(undefined *)(param_1 + local_10) = *(undefined *)(param_1 + local_8);
    *(undefined *)(local_8 + param_1) = uVar1;
  }
  return;
}


undefined4 __cdecl FUN_004019a3(int param_1,int param_2)

{
  HANDLE pvVar1;

  FUN_00401bb0();
  pvVar1 = CreateMutexA((LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES)0x0,1,"ND9487GF943GF4328FHG");
  if (pvVar1 != (HANDLE)0x0) {
    if (param_1 != 1) {
      Sleep(5000);
      DeleteFileA(*(LPCSTR *)(param_2 + 4));
    }
    FUN_004016de(s_lang32.ini_00403020);
    initRC4(0x405400,0x403040);
    FUN_0040192e();
    FUN_00401969();
  }
  return 0;
}


The decompiled code for the key schedule has the following element:
(param_2 + (local_10 & 3))

param_2 is the address of the key (as you have figured out already) and local_10 seems to be the loop variable (let's call it i). The & 3 reads out the least significant 2 bits of i, so when i goes from 0 to 255, i & 3 takes the values 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
That means only the first 4 bytes of the key are actually used, in other words the key is "If y".
Regarding the encoding: I encrypted b"ISOLANG 32ISOLANG 32[R" with the key b"If y" and got the following result:
HEX:    ee b3 c9 86 22 db 34 9a 5a f4 df 61 1f 56 30 25 ed bb cb fc fc f2
chr:     î  ³  É     "  Û  4     Z  ô  ß  a     V  0  %  í  »  Ë  ü  ü  ò

which is similar to your first string, with a few differences:

your string is longer
chr(0x86) doesn't give me the Dagger (U+2020), but the codepage Windows-1252 uses this mapping
chr(0xbb) gives me a different symbol which comes from Latin-1 Supplement / ISO/IEC 8859-1

When I print the string that I got, the values 0x9a and 0x1f are skipped, just like in your string. Note that these "invisible" characters in the cipher text are still important in the decryption, since skipping them desynchronizes the key stream. Knowing that there are gaps in the cipher text, I could try to guess where the gaps are in the second cipher text, in order to re-synchronize the decryption. However, you were able to decrypt the first string correctly, so I assume you have access to the raw bytes rather than an incomplete string representation, so you wouldn't have to guess any gaps.
Here is some of the code that I used for playing around with the strings:
def ksa(key):
    s = list(range(256))
    j = 0
    l = len(key)
    for i in range(256):
        j = (j + s[i] + key[i % l]) & 0xff
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
    return s

def keystream(key):
    s = ksa(key)
    i = j = 0
    while True:
        i = (i + 1) & 0xff
        j = (j + s[i]) & 0xff
        s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
        yield s[(s[i] + s[j]) & 0xff]

        
def crypt(key, msg):
    return bytes(a ^ b for a, b in zip(msg, keystream(key)))

plain_text = b"ISOLANG 32ISOLANG 32[R"
cipher_text = crypt(b"If y", plain_text)
print(cipher_text.hex(' '))


Thank you for the answer, but I think I missed something else because I have changed the key to If y in my code and sometimes the output is "readable" and sometimes not, with the first file I have "ISO⃪ANG 32ISOLANG 32[R     ˮ" which is understable and with the second part of the second file I have "ₗ.¢îÁÛ§Ƹ¬j)yÓ⁷Z]WfnØ(±³éä½ƹ" which is a bit weird

@Aimasu which encoding(s) do you use? I can't even reproduce the "...ISOLANG..." string

I just run the code in my post, I assume that is utf-8 but I'm not sure

@Aimasu I get "ISO⃪ANGà÷d?Pag<Æpȏ9Lâ" with your code. Note that by using ordandchr, your code decrypts string characters instead of single bytes, which means that if ord(c) > 255, only the least significant byte of c` is decrypted

Ok so I need to modify it a bit in order to treat single bytes

I have created a new fonction which only takes bytes for the first file I get ISOLANG 32ISOLANG 32[R which is readable (and the name of the malware by the way) but for the second file this is still weird text and string I don't know why it works well on one and not on the other

Maybe the state wasn't re-initialized after the first use, that might explain a different output.

But for each files I relaunch my script so the state should be re-initialized each times

sry, I meant maybe the malware doesn't do this.

no worries you helped me a lot bro, I will continue, I think I'm close to the answer, thanks again !
